# "Get" node doesn't work. I need a reference to a weapon

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

"Get" node inside this Animation BP https://i.imgur.com/0iRV6ni.png doesn't work for some reason. I checked it with "Print String". I checked every other relevant node and they work just fine. I need to "Set" my "Recurve Bow" variable to "BP_RecurveBow". Basically I need a reference to the weapon my character is holding. It is spawned and attached to "FirstPersonCamera" inside "BP_FirstPersonCharacter". https://i.imgur.com/FLUOe80.png

I wanted to get a reference to the weapon from "BP_FirstPersonCharacter" as it seemed the easiest way of doing it. If you can show me how to resolve the issue with the "Get" node or How to cast to "BP_RecurveBow" from an Animation BP I would be glad.